# Select ranges from tables of ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 range tables `ReceivedRanges` and  `DispatchedRanges`.

```
ReceivedRanges
 From  - To
     1 - 100000
200000 - 300000
350000 - 400000


DispatchedRanges
     From  - To
     10000 - 50000
    250000 - 275000
    350000 - 400000
```

I want to select new ranges from  above 2 tables. output ranges will be:

```
InventoryRanges
 From  - To
     1 - 9999
 50001 - 100000
200000 - 249999
275001 - 300000
```

how to select these ranges from tables of ranges.

**What I have Tried:**

Alternately I have tried with generating all individual received sequence numbers as `sequence` table and marked dispatched numbers as is dispatched true.
based on this table i am grouping and able  to retrieve `InventoryRanges`. But for these I need to store all the sequence number and update huge ranges during dispatch which will slowdown the dispatch process.

Comment: Don't forget to include the logic to derive to the required result

Answer (score 2):

I think this will cover all your cases of finding differences between ranges in SQL. Hope this helps you out:

```
create table received_ranges(item_id int, [from] int, [to] int);
create table dispatched_ranges(item_id int, [from] int, [to] int);

insert into received_ranges (item_id,[from],[to]) values
(1, 1,5000),
(1, 7000,8000),
(2, 6000,9000),
(3, 10000,15000),
(4, 20000,25000);

insert into dispatched_ranges (item_id,[from],[to]) values
(1, 1,250),
(2, 6000,7250),
(2, 7500,8000),
(2, 8200, 9000),
(3, 12000,14000),
(4, 20000,25000);


with dispatched_batch(dispatched_batch_num, received_item, received_from, received_to, dispatched_item, dispatched_from, dispatched_to) as
(select row_number() over (partition by rr.item_id, rr.[from] order by rr.[from]) dispatched_batch_num,
rr.item_id as received_item,
rr.[from] as received_from,
rr.[to] as received_to,
dr.item_id as dispatched_item,
dr.[from] as dispatched_from,
dr.[to] as dispatched_to
from received_ranges rr
left join
dispatched_ranges dr
ON
rr.item_id = dr.item_id
AND
dr.[from] >= rr.[from]
AND
dr.[to] <= rr.[to])
select * from
(select
[current].[received_item],
case when [next].dispatched_batch_num is null then
       case when [current].[received_to] <> [current].[dispatched_to] then
              [current].dispatched_to + 1 
            else
              0
            end
     else
       case when [next].[dispatched_from] <> [current].[dispatched_to]+1 then
              [current].[dispatched_to] + 1
            else
              0 
            end
     end
      as 'inventory from',
case when [next].dispatched_batch_num is null then
       case when [current].[received_to] <> [current].[dispatched_to] then
              [current].received_to
            else
              0
            end
     else
       case when [next].[dispatched_from] <> [current].[dispatched_to]+1 then
              [next].[dispatched_from] - 1
            else
              0 
            end
     end
      as 'inventory to'

from dispatched_batch [current]
left join
dispatched_batch [next]
on
[current].received_item = [next].received_item
and 
[current].dispatched_batch_num + 1 = [next].dispatched_batch_num

UNION

select 
[current].received_item,
case when [current].[dispatched_from] is null then
       [current].[received_from]
       else
       case when [previous].dispatched_batch_num is null then
              case when [current].[received_from] <> [current].[dispatched_from] then
                     [current].received_from 
                   else
                     0
                   end
            else
              case when [previous].[dispatched_to] <> [current].[dispatched_from]+1 then
                     [previous].[dispatched_to] + 1
                   else
                     0 
                   end
            end
        end
      as 'inventory from',
case when [current].[dispatched_to] is null then
       [current].[received_to]
       else
       case when [previous].dispatched_batch_num is null then
              case when [current].[received_from] <> [current].[dispatched_from] then
                     [current].dispatched_from -1
                   else
                     0
                   end
            else
              case when [previous].[dispatched_to] <> [current].[dispatched_from]+1 then
                     [current].[dispatched_from] - 1
                   else
                     0 
                   end
            end
        end
      as 'inventory to'

from dispatched_batch [current]
left join
dispatched_batch previous
on
[current].received_item = previous.received_item
and 
[current].dispatched_batch_num  = previous.dispatched_batch_num + 1) result
where [inventory from] <> 0;
```

Comment: works great but it is not covering all cases for ex if i had a range (1, 1,250),
(1, 251,260),
(1, 261,270), in dispatched ranges. will work around it.

Comment: yeah. should be a small fix I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table structure to be something like this:

```
create table received_ranges(received_date date, [from] int, [to] int);
create table dispatched_ranges(dispatched_date date, [from] int, [to] int);
```

and also assuming that there wont be multiple entries for each date in received_ranges or dispatched_ranges table (assumption made from the data provided) this query should work for you:

```
select date, inventory_from, inventory_to from
(select 
rr.received_date as 'date',
case when rr.[from] = dr.[from] then
     0
     else
      rr.[from] 
     end AS 'inventory_from',
case when rr.[from] = dr.[from] then
     0
     else
      dr.[from] - 1
     end AS 'inventory_to'
     from
received_ranges rr left join
dispatched_ranges dr
on
rr.received_date = dr.dispatched_date

UNION

Select 
rr.received_date as 'date',
case when rr.[to] = dr.[to] then 
     0
     else
      dr.[to]+1 
     end AS 'inventory_from',
case when rr.[to] = dr.[to] then
     0
     else
     rr.[to]
     end AS 'inventory_to'
     from
received_ranges rr left join
dispatched_ranges dr
on
rr.received_date = dr.dispatched_date) result
where (inventory_from == 0 and inventory_to == 0) <> TRUE
order by inventory_from;
```

Comment: As per assumtions it works. but in my case there is multiple entries for same date.

Comment: Do you have multiple entries only in DispatchedRanges or in both?

Comment: Both tables, here i can say instead of date we can also take additional field ItemID for join purpose. So same item can be received and dispatched multiple times with range of serial numbers.